# Embedding a video in another video stream

Tags: video, stream, embedded-resource

It's possible and how can I do a real time embedding of two videos so that a software like vlc follow the stream like being only one video, stream the first one until a defined time, stream the second, and resume the first one until finishes?
In other words, if I have a video stream like this:

```
<?php

$fp=fopen("video.mp4","rb");

while(!feof($fp)){
echo fread($fp,8096);
}

fclose($fp);

?>
```

how can I "include" a second video in the same stream? Like:

```
<?php

$fp=fopen("video.mp4","rb");
$fp2=fopen("video2.mp4","rb");

while(!feof($fp)){
if($condition==1){
echo fread($fp2,8096);
}
else echo fread($fp,8096);
}

fclose($fp);
fclose($fp2);
?>
```

I've done it in simple php, but there's no problem if I must do it in C or C++.
And there's some tools for doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Video file formats don't have `#include` directives or anything of this sort...

I can think of several solutions to your problem. One is, if supported by your player, is to provide it with a playlist rather than the URL of the first media.

The other, which I'd use if the player does not support playlists, is to create a new media file from the two videos stitched together. If the media format you're using is MP4, you'd probably need to create the combined video offline, as MP4 creation in real-time is quite complicated (the header of MP4 files contains very detailed indices of the remainder of the file, so most MP4 writers write the header only after writing all the video data). But offline, it is quite simple, you can use a tool like ffmpeg or VLC to do that. If both videos are coded by the same encoder with similar parameters, the creation of the joint video file is very fast as you don't need to re-encode (you can use `ffmpeg -vcodec copy -acodec copy`). Here's instructions on concatenation with ffmpeg: [ffmpeg FAQ](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#toc-Concatenating-at-the-file-level)